# Could anyone with access to a nation's nuclear launch codes unilaterally fire nukes as they please?

Tags: nuclear-weapons, united-states

If someone were to have a country's (Take the U.S, for the sake of being specific) nuclear launch codes, could he unilaterally fires nukes as he pleases?

Assumptions:

1) He's among the military's top brass and can, conveniently, access practically any room in the White House without questions being asked.

2) He's got a loyal team of about a dozen people at his disposal, so he doesn't have to do everything himself.

3) He has access to the President's "nuclear football", and managed to obtain a copy of the launch/verification codes.

4) He decides to fire the missile(s) on the *same* day he obtains the codes, so even changing the codes on a daily basis is no impediment to his plan.

5) He already knows where a particular launch site is.

6) He's got 10 minutes to get into the Oval Office/Situation Room, punch in the codes and get out before anyone suspects anything/ walks in.

Comment: Vaguely relevant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1983_Soviet_nuclear_false_alarm_incident

Comment: Probably worth reading: Eric Schlosser, _Command and Control_. https://www.amazon.com/Command-Control-Damascus-Accident-Illusion/dp/0143125788

Comment: Sounds like it depends on who's nuclear bombs you want to fire. Like it might be easier to fire them from france or Israel or India (just random example of people who have them) and set off a war than to go straight for the US nukes which are probably some of the best protected ones. Do you particularly want american nukes?

Comment: This question appears to be a reality-check on the plot for your story, rather than a request to build anything. Voting to close as _too story-based_.

Comment: @Frostfyre Reality check on the plot seems to me to be perfectly on-topic here...

Comment: @kingledion Reality-check questions about creations in a world are on-topic, such as asking if a tree can naturally bear multiple kinds of fruit; this is something being created for the world. This is a plot-centric question asking about the specifics of real-world policies and practices. Questions about plot are specifically mentioned as off-topic.

Comment: I suggest reading a lot more Tom Clancy, before you go down this path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, after ordering the strike the Pentagon war room askes a [verification code over voice communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_Codes). Without that verification code by voice the strike will not be initiated. So unless he remains long enough to make that call it won't happen. If he can, it will move forward.

However that verification order is send not just to the launch crew but several command centers as well. With still 3 minutes to go before launch those command centers will know a strike is initiate and can contact the launch site directly as that location is embedded in the order.

Submarines take an additional 10 minutes to fire. Although I can't tell you exactly why. Their launch procedures are longer thus would give even more time to prevent launch.

Comment: subs take longer to fire because they have to safely reach launch depth and verify that their immediate area is 'safe' for them to launch.  Silos literally have to open a door and turn some keys.

Answer (score 3):

As with most of the other respondents, I am going to say a firm **No.**

Let's walk through the entire scenario.  You have a high level adviser with a team in place in one of the most secure areas in the United States, presumably with access to the President, Vice President, and all of their staff, but the President is not part of this conspiracy and will not cooperate to launch nuclear weapons.

Your first hurdle is getting the authorization codes you need.  It is presumable that you could replace the "Football Carrier" with one of your people, but the football is only one part of the recipe to launch Armageddon.  To authorize the attacks, the President also has the "Biscuit," a gold credit-card sized piece of plastic that must be physically broken to reveal a code used to authorize the attack.  Without the President on board, you couldn't authorize a launch.  The President's identity is also verified by SecDef, so unless SecDef is in your conspiracy, you have that hurdle as well.

Let's sidestep that issue.  Say you incapacitate the president, and have the VP on your side, using his football and his "biscuit" to authorize the strike, or managing to give the real President sufficient evidence that he believes a strike is needed.  You send out the nuclear launch command to NORAD.  Various nuclear facilities are activated, verified, etc, and prepped for the launch.  Given that we have never gone to the brink with nuclear weapons since WW2, it is possible that operators will refuse to launch.  Just from sheer probability, some will fail to launch for various reasons.  At least a few weapons will launch under any scenario where the President (Or VP with the President out of the way) authorizes a strike.

However, it would probably be easier (with the military connections and access you have) to secure a "Boomer" sub.  Russia is almost guaranteed to counter-strike if they are attacked, and one the nukes are in the air, the US will have no options left but to strike back or die quietly.

Answer (score 2):

Defenitely **NO**

Anyone could use two-factor authorisation just for Google account: using password and some tokens. When you buy something strange then bank could call you and ensure it's your order.

I'm sure that nuke has more than 2 security levels.

---

Just what I were add in the system:

- special oficer who holds key in addition to the president's codes.
- call back for president
- acceptance from headquarters
- commander on the base who should enter its own code to launch the rocket.

Comment: Not really. After an order is given with the correct code a single verification call is made asking for a second passcode. If that passes all is good to go. Of course there several warning triggers along the way but no true gateways.

Comment: ok. Since we are on world **building** site I wrote what is could be easily done. I don't exactly know how it work in real world :)

Comment: It would make sense if it had more layers I agree. Sadly it doesn't, though there several warning signals.